# Event scheduling on startup mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created some event. It is running on the time on which I have created it. But I want to run the event when ever mysql server is started. 
For Example I have created an event called CL_PL_CREDIT code looks like,

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT RURALSHORES2.UpLv
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MONTH
    DO
      BEGIN
      update emp_lv_rem set cl_count=cl_count+1,pl_count=pl_count+1.25 where emp_id in (select emp_id from emp_main where EmploymentType="Permanent" or EmploymentType="Regular");
      update emp_lv_rem set cl_count=1,pl_count=1 where emp_id in (select emp_id from emp_main where EmploymentType="Probation");
      update emp_lv_rem set cl_count=1,pl_count=0 where emp_id in (select emp_id from emp_main where EmploymentType="Contract" or EmploymentType="Partime" or EmploymentType="Trainee" or EmploymentType="Consultant");
update emp_lv_rem set cl_count=0,pl_count=0 where emp_id in (select emp_id from emp_main where EmploymentType="Contract" and EmploymentType<>"Partime" and EmploymentType<>"Trainee" and EmploymentType<>"Consultant" and EmploymentType="Permanent" and EmploymentType="Regular" and EmploymentType="Probation");

    END |;

delimiter ;
```

When I type show events it is showing as starts 2013-08-23 10:42:53, but I want to run it on every 1st day of month when ever server starts.

Comment: Do you mean that the server restart every 1st day of month and that you want to execute the event whenever the server restart, or that you want to execute the event every 1st day month?

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute it every 1st day of month you should add the start date:

```
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 MONTH
  STARTS AT '2013-09-01 00:00:00'
```